# Get value from map returned from function with implicit in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, implicit

Having an implicit value and function defined as follows

```
implicit val v = 0

def function(implicit v: Int): Map[String, String] = Map("key" -> "value")
```

I can do

```
function.get("key") // res0: Option[String] = Some(value)
function(v)("key") // res0: String = value
```

but the following doesn't compile

```
function("key")
```

So how can I in one go access a map using parentheses and pass implicit parameter?

Comment: The ugly way: `(function _)("key")` (I wonder why it even works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are your options:

```
scala> function.apply("key")
res6: String = value

scala> function(implicitly)("key")
res7: String = value
```

As compiler can't know if you want to pass an implicit parameter explicitly or call apply method, designers decided it will mean passing the implicit parameter.

You can either give up on using the syntactic sugar and just use `apply` that will resolve ambiguity or you can pass the parameter explicitly, but let the compiler find the value.